# Xamarin Forms Trigger on Entry to change the text color does not work?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
 var trigger = new Trigger(typeof(Entry));
        trigger.Property = Entry.IsEnabledProperty;
        trigger.Value = false;
        trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Entry.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.Red});

        entry.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

The above code does not work, if I replace the Text Color property with Background Color, it works.

Is it a bug in Xamarin Forms? I am on Xamarin Forms 2.3.0.49

Thanks